# Angular Material styles not applying on child component

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I am facing a issue with angular material default styles.
I have a parent dashboard component which has child component named
"HomComponent" and "RegistrationComponent".Angular Material's Input box and button works fine in dashboard page but in child component only HTmlbutton and input box are seen.
Please see the code below.

`DashBoardRouting.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
import { home} from './home/home-routing.module';
import { regis } from './registration/registration-routing.module';

export const dashboard: Routes = [
  {
    path : 'dashboard',
    component :DashboardComponent,
    children:[
      ...home,
      ...regis
    ]
  },

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(dashboard)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule { }
```

`HomeCompoennt.html`:

```html
<form class="example-form" >
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="Username">
  </mat-form-field>
  </form>
```

`app.module.ts`:

```ts
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule,CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AppRoutingRoutingModule } from './app-routing-routing.module';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {MatStepperModule} from '@angular/material/stepper';
import {CdkTableModule} from '@angular/cdk/table';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { LoginModule } from './login/login.module';
import { DashboardModule } from './dashboard/dashboard.module';
import 'hammerjs';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,DashboardComponent, LoginComponent

  ],
  imports: [

    BrowserModule,BrowserAnimationsModule,AppRoutingRoutingModule,MatInputModule,MatButtonModule,
    MatStepperModule,CdkTableModule,FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule,LoginModule,DashboardModule
  ],

  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas:[CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Why do you need `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA`?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `MatFormFieldModule`. `MatInputModule` allows native `<input>` and `<textarea>` elements to work with `<mat-form-field>`, while `MatFormFieldModule` is for `<mat-form-field>` itself.

P.S. Consider using a dedicated module for Angular Material components.

```ts
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';

// ...

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatFormFieldModule,
    // ...
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

Comment: hi, I tried importing form module as well but it does not work.

Comment: Downvoter, could you explain why you downvoted the answer?